# EF - Assigning Id of related entites without re-looping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, npgsql

Please guide me, in my code. I iterate to create a model called DataSetAsset and DataSetColumn. This will be use for creating DataSetPoint. I have this code

```
using (var transaction = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
{
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        lineNumber++;

        foreach (var column in columns)
        {
            var dataSetAsset = new DataSetAsset
            {
                ...
            };

            _context.DataSetAssets.Add(dataSetAsset);

            var dataSetColumn = new DataSetColumn 
            {
                ...
            };

            _context.DataSetColumns.Add(dataSetColumn);

            var dataSetPoint = new DataSetPoint
            {
                DataSetColumn = dataSetColumn,
                DataSetAsset = dataSetAsset
            };

            // detach dataSetPoint so it wont get insert on SaveChangesAsync
            _context.Entry(dataSetPoint).State = EntityState.Detached;
             
            dataSetPoints.Add(dataSetPoint);
        }
    }

    // this will create the dataSetAsset and dataSetColumn
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync(_http, cancellation);

    // upload the dataSetPoints data
    var uploader = new NpgsqlBulkUploader(_context);
    await uploader.InsertAsync(dataSetPoints);

    await transaction.CommitAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

this code was just looping through all the items in the csv and creating a dataSetAsset and dataSetColumn which is required for creating dataSetPoint. dataSetPoint could be thousands of values thats why I move it out(or detached it) and use NpgsqlBulkUploader for me to improve its performance. But what happens is since the dataSetAsset and dataSetColumn is required in creating a dataSetPoint, it keeps throwing me an error of having the value for dataSetAsset .Id and dataSetColumn.Id being 0 and lead to Primary Key errors.

What I want to know is if there's a possibility that on SaveChanges, the id for dataSetAsset and dataSetColumn will be set automatically for dataSetPoint rather than going on another loop just to set it. Those ids where set after SaveChanges but its on the navigation property and not in the dataSetPoint property. NpgsqlBulkUploader does not work similar to EF which if you assign the related entities then the Id was considered as set.

**UPDATE**

[image]

added a screenshot above what I currently have after SaveChangesAsync call. as you can see the DataSetColumnId value was still 0, but its navigation property it already have the value. I want that Id value to be set in DataSetColumnId.

Comment: What's the problem wit looping? This things don't happen magically, with the normal usage something else (EF Core infrastructure) is performing that loop :for you". But since you are bypassing EF Core, you have to do that yourself. Btw, what do you mean by "ids are set on **navigation property**" ?  Can we see the relevant parts of the entities (PKs, navigation properties and FKs)?

Comment: @IvanStoev with looping it just saying that you will go over the rows and cols the second time around. Im sure it will affect the performance but I believe it will. I've updated it so you can see what are inside the dataSetPoints properties have now

Comment: You don't need to go over rows and columns again if you keep `DataSetPoint` objects in some list, which you seem to already do have with `dataSetPoints`  variable.

Comment: @IvanStoev the dataSetPoints consists all the rows and columns in my csv

Comment: Third party library knows nothing about change tracker and related entities. At first iinsert Dataset, DatasetColumn - SaveChanges. Then use these Ids for DatsSetPoint (only ids), then you can call BulkCopy.

Comment: `DataSetColumn` is an object tracked by EF Core, that's why its PK property is set. But by detaching `DataSetPoint` objects, EF Core has no more access to them, hence cannot set the FKs for you. You must iterate the `dataSetPoints` list (`for each dataSetPoint in dataSetPoints`) and do  `{ dataSetPoint.DataSetColumnId = dataSetPoint.DataSetColumn.Id;  /* same for other FKs */}`